# How to save user input data in the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a two page form, when a user fills out the first page he/she can either click Save For Later, or click Next and proceed to the next page and continue filling out the form. It is done through jquery. What I cannot figure out how to do is, how can I save the user input in the form, so if the browser crashes, internet goes out, or user simply wants to save form and come back to it later, the filled out information sits in the input fields. What is a method to accomplish that?

Comment: Thats great. Please show your form then. The code?

Comment: Do you want to store it on your server or is storing it on the local computer fine as well?

Comment: Look into web storage:  http://caniuse.com/#search=storage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It think that you can realise it with storing the login credintials with PHP in a session or something like this. If the user visits the website again your PHP-script sees that there is a session with credentials and you can show them to the user.

An other method would be to save this data in a localStorage on the device of the visitor but I wouldn't use this method because not all browser are accepting localStorages.

Comment: `Session` is server side handled and not confined to PHP!
BTW, if browser crashes or PC restart then will the session OR localStrorage work?

Comment: there is no way to fix the problem that the data gets removed when the pc ist crashing.

Comment: browser crashed or PC restart : in both case saving data to any local file works fine. And saving to database is safe for the users to fill up later.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less general solution to your problem: use `localStorage` to store the user input:

```
<body onload="if(localStorage.userEdits){document.getElementById('name').value=localStorage.userEdits}" id="myForm">
    <form>
        <input id="name" type="text" onkeyup="localStorage.userEdits=this.value"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

It will store the value of your input every time you press a button on your keyboard to type something, and retrieve this info on load.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can easily achieve this behavior.
One of them, is to provide **draft**  feature. This feature will allow user to save the form data when...
 a) They click next
 b) they leave and session is timed out
 c) Complete the form and don't want to submit it

This way is more secure and reliable.